# Problems serializing my scikit-learn (sklearn) grid-search classifier in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, scikit-learn, scikits

I ran the grid-search classifier from below in *iPython*:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html

and then tried to serialize it by pickling, but received the following traceback:

```
In [6]: with open('clf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(clf, f)
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-577559be619c> in <module>()
      1 with open('clf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
----> 2     cPickle.dump(clf, f)
      3 

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc in     _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     68     else:
     69         if base is self.__class__:
---> 70             raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
     71         state = base(self)
     72     args = (self.__class__, base, state)

TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

Is there a work-around?

I am using the latest beta of both iPython and sklearn.

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to tell the exact name of the sklearn class your are trying to pickle as long as the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid Search classifier used to keep all estimators which created the pickle problem. This problem has been [noted before](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/565#issuecomment-4476779) and [solved](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/770). This patch [comment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/770#issuecomment-7182976) tells that you can pickle the classifier by just pickling `best_estimator_`. In your case that would be:

```
cPickle.dump(clf.best_estimator_, f)
```